# Does SQL Server store the history tables of system-versioned (temporal) tables "normally"?

Tags: sql-server, temporal-tables

I was wondering whether SQL Server uses any kind of fancy storage -- for instance, storing only changes -- to save space and/or facilitate searches.

If the storage is "flat", like in the primary table, then might it not be advantageous to split system-versioned tables up between volatile and non-volatile fields?  Like, if an Employee's Name, SSN and Email seldom change, but his SickDaysThisYear does (I'm not saying this is a good schema), then it seems wasteful to be duplicating the first three fields every time the fourth changes.

Comment: The storage is essentially "flat". This can be observed by performing an update to a row that doesn't actually change any data being visible in the temporal history. I wouldn't recommend splitting the non-volatile fields off in anything other than extreme circumstances.

Comment: Thanks, @gvee, for the answer.  Can you elaborate on why you wouldn't split the tables, or what you would consider "extreme circumstances"?  I was thinking my DB may have tens of millions of history records with only a few fields changing...